# Why does this code keep throwing this error? TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object

Tags: python

My code is throwing this error:

```
defs = LI_re.findall(text)
TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

So here is my code that I am using to clean a piece of extracted information from a dictionary website.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
clean_defs = []
LI_re = re.compile(r'<LI>(.*)</LI>') 
HTML_re = re.compile(r'<[^>]+>\s*')
defs = LI_re.findall(text) # THE ERROR HAPPENS HERE
# remove internal tags                                                                                      
for d in defs:
    clean_d = HTML_re.sub('',d)
    if clean_d: clean_defs.append(clean_d)

return clean_defs #My return from the function or whatever
```

Comment: `text` is a byte stream, not a string. I take it that you are using Python 3. You need to convert `text` to a string.

Comment: ok so would str(txt) work>

Comment: Instead of asking, why don't you try it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`text` is obviously a byte object.  There are several solutions.  You could alter `text` to a string:

```
text = text.decode()
```

This will give string (`str`) results.

OR alternatively change the regular expressions to use byte objects:

```
LI_re = re.compile(br'<LI>(.*)</LI>')
HTML_re = re.compile(br'<[^>]+>\s*')
```

This will give byte object results.